# Was a drop in standards of living a significant factor in the revolutions of 1848?

Tags: 19th-century, economy, revolution, industrial-revolution

A lot ink has been expended discussing the **revolutions of 1848** and their causes, only a small fraction of which I have read.

From my point of view, there seem to be two main schools of thought in explaining why the revolutions broke out when they did:

- The **first school of thought**, of which the [Wikipedia article on the revolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutions_of_1848) seems like a good representative, is that **industrialisation caused a drop the standard of living** of the urban poor - to such a point that they rose up in revolt.
- The **second school of thought** advances the counter-intuitive notion that **revolutions tend to happen when things are getting better**. Conditions for the poor leading up to 1848 were not
  markedly worse than before, but, the new urban bourgeoisie, on the other hand, was in a stronger position than ever; and the revolutions of 1848 are best understood as an attempt by this class to displace the old feudal aristocracy. (I'm no expert on the man, but I believe this was Marx's interpretation of events.)

**Was there a drop in standards of living in France, Germany, Austria and Italy in the years leading up to 1848? And if so, was this a significant factor in bringing about the revolutions?**

Comment: Was there a drop in standards of living is an objective question; was it a significant factor involves a much more complex model & judgement.

Comment: Worth plugging Mike Duncan's Revolutions podcast.  I believe [this episode](https://www.revolutionspodcast.com/2017/08/index.html) is most relevant.

Comment: I believe the point of the second school of thought is that when conditions are bad, people are too focused on survival to think of inciting a revolution, but once conditions start improving -- the common people have enough to eat, they have shelter, their economic security is better -- they are able to vent their anger over the unfair treatment they experienced. It is that an improving economic environment can lead to a violent revolution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [the article](https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/15926/1/economic_crises.pdf) "Economic Crises and the European Revolutions of 1848" (Berger and Sporer, 2001):

> Recent historical research tends to view the 1848 revolutions in Europe as caused by a surge of radical ideas and by long-term socioeconomic problems. However, many contemporary observers interpreted much of the upheaval as a consequence of short-term  economic  causes,  specifically  the  serious  shortfall  in  food  supply  that  had shaken  large  parts  of  the  Continent  in  1845–1847,  and  the  subsequent  industrial slump. Applying standard quantitative methods to a data set of 27 European countries, we show that **it was mainly immediate economic misery, and the fear thereof, that triggered the European revolutions of 1848**.

While this doesn't rule out multiple, contradictory dynamics going on at once, it's pretty clear evidence that precarious living standards had an important role.

Comment: Thank you. I really wasn't expecting such a definite answer to a somewhat broad question, but the argument that Berger and Sporer put forth is compelling. Thank you again.